# VS Code extension

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I am using VS Code but my problem are extensions. I installed some extensions but they are not working. The extensions are all added to the workspace, but when I right click in the editor no option from the installed extension shows up.

[image: not showing any option]

Answer (score 0):

Most of VS-Code extensions aren't integrated inside the UI. Most of the time you should use them by the command palette (`CTRL`+ `Shift` + `P`) with the extension name or action.
For your extension "Open In browser", you have to press `ALT` + `B` to launch it.
Take the time to read extension Readme, they don't all work the same